# Codeigniter - missing argument 1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having problems with my college assignments. I'm learning to make a update function trough codeigniter, then I got an error :

Missing argument 1 for Account::update()

When I press "Submit" button.

Controller :

```
class Account extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('cpanel/account/account_model');
}

public function update($nim) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nim', 'nim', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'nama', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sandi', 'sandi', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telp', 'telp', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['akun'] = $this->account_model->detail();
        $data['detail'] = $this->account_model->detail($nim);
        $data = array('title'=> 'Mengubah Data Akun : '.$data['detail']['ortu_nama'], 'akun'=> $this->account_model->detail(), 'detail'=> $this->account_model->detail($nim), 'isi'=>'cpanel/account/account_edit_view');

        $this->load->view('cpanel/layout/wrapper',$data);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'ortu_nim_mhs' => $this->input->post('nim'),
            'ortu_nama' => $this->input->post('nama'),
            'ortu_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'ortu_telp' => $this->input->post('telp')
            );

        $this->account_model->update($data);
        $konten = array('title'=>'Perubahan Data Sukses', 'isi'=>'cpanel/account/success_view');
        $this->load->view('cpanel/layout/wrapper', $konten);
    }
}}
```

Model :

```
class Account_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    $this->load->database();
}

public function update($data) {
    $this->db->where('ortu_nim_mhs', $data['ortu_nim_mhs']);
    return $this->db->update('user_ortu', $data);
}

public function detail($nim = FALSE) {
    if ($nim === FALSE) {
        $query = $this->db->get('user_ortu');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_ortu', array('ortu_nim_mhs'=>$nim));
    return $query->row_array();
}}
```

Comment: hi, in your method **update** what is the variable **$nim** change `public function update($nim) {` to `public function update( ) {`

Comment: Missing argument  1 usually means that it is missing when you called the update function. Find where you call update from and check which parameter you are passing and if that it how Codeigniter intends it to be passed. Usually, form params are passed by POST

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$data = array();` in model function

```
public function update($data = array()) {
   $this->db->where('ortu_nim_mhs', $data['ortu_nim_mhs']);
   return $this->db->update('user_ortu', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your above code if you are submitting form with `POST` method than function argument is not required. Please check below.

```
public function update() {
    // Your code
}
```

But in case if you submitting form with `get` method than you need to set data for validation first, like given below.

```
public function update() {
    $this->form_validation->set_data($this->input->get());
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nim', 'nim', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'nama', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sandi', 'sandi', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telp', 'telp', 'required');

    // Your other code
}
```

This will help you. Let me know if it not works.